# SQLITE SELECT a Date Integer column IF all records for that Date are NULL in another parameter

Tags: sqlite, select, null, group-by

I'm probably approaching this the wrong way...

I have a table with the Date as an `INTEGER` in format `yyyymmdd` - named `DateInteger`
I have another field `Method` which is `NULL` by default. This field is updated by various queries.
I'd like to produce a report that illustrates the days where ALL the `Method` fields are `NULL` (Grouping/Ordering by `DateInteger`).

```
`SELECT DateInteger,COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Method IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DateInteger HAVING Count(*)=0 ORDER BY DateInteger ASC;` doesn't give any results, as the days which have only `NULL` values seem to be missed out...
```

How do I make the query include / look at these days ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I'd like to produce a report that illustrates the days where ALL the Method fields are NULL (Grouping/Ordering by DateInteger).`

This will return a distinct set of datefield values where the method column value is *not* null:

```
            select distinct yourDateField from yourTable 
           where method is not null
```

If I understand you, these datefield values above are the ones you do *not* want: you need all of the method values in every row with a given date to be null. Thus, the datefield values you *do* want cannot be in the set above.

```
          select T.yourDateField, NotWanted.Unwanted
          from yourTable as T
          left join
          (
            select distinct yourDateField as Unwanted from yourTable 
           where method is not null
          ) as NotWanted

          on T.yourDateField = NotWanted.Unwanted

          where NotWanted.Unwanted is null
```

EDIT:  you might also try this:

```
        select T.yourDateField from yourTable as T
        where not exists
        (
           select yourDateField from yourTable as T2
           where T1.yourDateField = T2.yourDateField
           and T2.method is not null

        )
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. That does work - takes about 25s for query to complete on a dual core system with DB of 60000 rows.

Comment: Is your datefield indexed? How about method field? How long does this take: `select distinct yourDateField as Unwanted from yourTable 
           where method is not null`

Comment: Odd. 'Method' wasn't indexed - but adding index didn't improve things. The `select distinct yourDateField as Unwanted from yourTable where method is not null` took 25s - and DateInteger already has an index... same if i change the query to `select yourDateField as Unwanted from yourTable where method is not null group by yourDateField`

Comment: How does the `where not exists` approach perform relative to the left join? It does not do a `distinct`.

Comment: Odd. That takes even longer - about 40s to complete. System is a Dual-Core @2.50GHz and 1Gb DDR2 RAM (work system)... but the database lives on the SAN. Even `SELECT yourDateField FROM yourTable;` takes 30s... so must be related to disk access/SAN etc aswell as size of DB... not the query itself.

Comment: It's either disk subsystem latency or choked bandwidth when that simple select against a single indexed column takes 30 seconds on a table with only 60K records. Are you certain yourDateField has an index--and that it's a simple (non-composite) index? Sounds like slow-seek-time to me.You could always copy the database file locally to test.

Comment: I used `CREATE INDEX "UsedDateRange" ON "yourTable" ("yourdateField" ASC);`. Must be disk related - it runs in a second or two as an in-memory DB...

Comment: In that case, I'd appreciate your accepting the answer(s). I'm trying to build up some points to put a big bounty on a question I myself plan to ask.